# Find My iPhone: Location not updating

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I dropped my iPhone while running this morning and within literally 5 minutes on a deserted street, it was picked up!! I think it was immediately turned off as its been going straight to voicemail and shows as offline.

However, I was able to track the location successfully with Find my iPhone but 2 hours ago the location stopped updating - it now says old location in red and won't refresh. Why would the location stop updating?

Comment: Maybe the battery died or the phone is out of range of service or maybe it was turned off or maybe you are out of cellular data, there are loads of possibilities.